# Using touch events on canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I have a program to draw on a HTML canvas with JS. It works fine with the mouse, but when I try the same on  on a touch-based device, it draws only a dot. How do I fix this?

Here's the code that handles the mouse events:

```
let m = document.getElementById('m-container');
const onMouseMove = (e) =>{
  m.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
  m.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
}
m.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
m.addEventListener('mousedown', setPosition);
m.addEventListener('mouseenter', setPosition);
function setPosition(e) {
  pos.x = parseInt(document.getElementById('m-container').style.left, 10);
  pos.y = parseInt(document.getElementById('m-container').style.top, 10);
}
function draw(e) {
  // mouse left button must be pressed
  if (e.buttons !== 1 || isDragging) return;

    if(mode=="pen"){
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation="source-over";
    } else {
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-out";
    }
    
  ctx.beginPath(); // begin

  ctx.lineWidth = currentDrawWidth;
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.strokeStyle = currentDrawColour;
  ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y); // from
  setPosition(e);
  ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y); // to

  ctx.stroke(); // draw it!
}
```

Here's the code to handle the touch events:

```
m.addEventListener('touchmove', touchdraw);
m.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
    setPositionTouch(e)
});
m.addEventListener('touchend', function (e) {
    setPositionTouch(e)
});
function setPositionTouch(e) {
  pos.x = e.clientX;
  pos.y = e.clientY;
}
function touchdraw(e) {
  
    if(mode=="pen"){
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation="source-over";
    } else {
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-out";
    }
    
  ctx.beginPath(); // begin

  ctx.lineWidth = currentDrawWidth;
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.strokeStyle = currentDrawColour;
  ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y); // from
  setPositionTouch(e);
  ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y); // to

  ctx.stroke(); // draw it!
}
```

`mode` is declared separately.

Comment: [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55898328/the-touch-event-in-my-canvas-is-not-working-as-intended-and-i-am-not-able-to-ide) may help.